# Show Google Photos as Chromecast backdrop?

Tags: google-plus, google-photos

It looks like Chromecast backdrops [pulls its photos from Google+ photos](https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/6097224?hl=en), but Google+ [shut down its photo feature](https://plus.google.com/+googleplus/posts/d1XubVAZ5hV) on 8/1/2015.

First, what gives?  Second, is there any way presently to show my [Google Photos](http://photos.google.com) collection on the backdrop?

Comment: Did you try activating the "Your Photos" feature on Chromecast? Google+ Photos and Google Photos use the same image store so anything that was available in one is available in the other.

Comment: @abraham yes, I have the "your photos" feature activated, but the only folders that show up are the ones on my Google+ profile.  I have thousands more photos on "Google Photos" in folders that aren't available to select from the Chromecast configuration.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is about a device managed by mobile apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create "Google Photos" folders.  Just select some photos and add them to a new folder at photos.google.com, and the new folder will appear in your Chromecast backdrop folder list, where you can select it for display.

Note: if you want to add a bunch of photos at once to a folder (either by date, or by selecting a face using the facial recognition search,) you can select a single photo's checkbox with a click, then shift click another photo.  All of the pictures in between will also be selected.